# Where should I post my question when it overlaps multiple sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, asking-questions

Soon I will be starting with my side project to try and get out of corporate development and into game development. And I am sure I will have a lot of questions - I already have, but I first need to try and figure it out on my own.

I can see that some of the questions I have will overlap between sites. Most will be relating to game development, but will also have non game related implementations.

As I am sure someone will ask me for the types of questions or a question example, here is one:

> One of the things I need to figure out is how to store each player's map, and map exploration. I am reading up on a couple of options and one option I am looking at with regards to map exploration storage is a quadtree, more specifically about how I will store the quadtree data on disc/db.

Now I have not done much reading on this topic yet, so it is not a real question, but an example of how the questions can overlap between Game Development and Stack Overflow.

Should I ask those questions that overlap game development an non game development in Stack Overflow rather than Game Development, and have it moved to Game Development if it is deemed too specific? Or should I post it all in Game Development since my questions arise from and will be implemented in Game Development?

Side question: what is the impact of having a couple/too many of your posts moved to another site?

---

I have tried to find similar questions here on meta, but topics like [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207856/where-to-post-if-questions-fit-multiple-networks) ended up a discussion on the validity of the questions rather than guidelines as to where to post questions. So I am still uncertain about the rule of thumb regarding this.

Comment: The one that fits *best*? The one that gives the type of answers *most desired* for particular question? It's good to hang around both sites, earn some rep, get to know how people answer on them.

Comment: The way I usually decide is that I put  specific programming questions on stack overflow and more conceptual questions (algorithms, techniques etc) on game development. But where a question is a good fit on both (relatively rare) its ultimately up to you

Comment: This is a shameless plug of [an answer of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196148/182513) on a similar question.  That question was very specific on what the topic was, but I think there is enough to help.

Comment: But in general, on-topic posts are not migrated.  Since programming questions would be on-topic in both locations, then you shouldn't have to worry about it getting moved if you ask on SO or GameDev.  Only good but off-topic questions are migrated.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Shameless plug of a good answer. Thank you. "And there is nothing stopping you from asking the question in one location, evaluating the answers for a few days, then flagging it for migration if you don't think your answers are good enough." Very good to know. Can I post an answer linking to your answer? Do you post the answer linking to your answer? Or do someone flag this topic pointing to that answer?

Comment: @ufis If you think that question fully answered your question we can vote to close as duplicate, which will put all the nessissary links in

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, I think that answer (and comments in that question) was what I was looking for. That answers my question.

Comment: @ufis one point to mention is even if you flag it for migration, the is no guarantee that a moderator will actually migrate it without a good reason, so don't just pick 1 site and then move it to the other.  You need to give the mod a valid reason to move it.  I'm going to edit that bit into my original answer now

Comment: @psubsee2003 That was my understanding of it, 'valid reason'. But it is good to know that *I can request it myself* - with valid reason. All part of learning what is possible here, as well as what is acceptable. Like Molot posted in the first comment: get to know the people (and by extension the sites)